# Visual Studio 2015 Community not getting installed.

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition

I downloaded the exe file and started installing the VS 2015 Community Edition. It's been an hour or so, but still it's installing.

Anyone faced the same issue? What could be the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is certainly not a quick install, and if you are using the web installer it has a lot of data to download: on a slow connection this could easily be a problem. What does the UI show it is doing?

Comment: @Richard The acquiring is over, but the installation is in the same position for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue. (Creating Restore point in progress over 1h) Try to reboot your system and run installation again.